# Objectify 4 transactions

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, objectify

With Objectify 4 I am trying to throw a controlled exception inside a transaction. As vrun() interface does not allow throwing exceptions, I have to catch it. I do it, and then I want to perform the rollback, but when the transaction finishes and it all fails (I think it is because it tries to do a commit), not even doing the rollback. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Code example:

```
    ofy().transact(new VoidWork() {

      @Override
      public void vrun() {
        //do something
        //...
        //find someting wrong and want to throw an exception
        try {
          throw new MyException(); //throw the exception
        } catch (MyException e) {
          ofy().getTransaction().rollback(); //catch it and perform rollback
        }
      }
    });
    //an error occurs
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do. Exceptions thrown out of the run()/vrun() method rollback the transaction; you should not do this yourself.

Comment: yeah, but the thing is: if I try to throw an Exception (e.g. "throw new Exception();") inside the run()/vrun() my IDE (Eclipse) forces to me to try catch that exception, so I cannot throw it out. sorry about my explanation, is it more clear now?

Comment: You need to throw something that extends RuntimeException. This is basic Java - I suggest reading Bruce Eckles' free book "Thinking In Java": http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! We were missing that!